# How to deploy/serve a vite app without a 3rd party

Tags: vue.js, vite

I was wondering how I'm supposed to serve a vite app in (for example) a docker container.
I cant use something like "npx serve" because it breaks both vite proxies, aswell as vue router (I use vue).
Is there a way to serve my app, so it doesn't break?
I don't want to use "npm run dev" in a production enviorment.

I tried to use vite-plugin-node, but I don't really want to rely on such projects. It doesn't work in the first place.

Comment: Ever heard of `npm run build` and then serving static HTML/CSS/JS through whatever way you want?

Comment: Hey Aaron, the way this usually works is that you generate static files from your source code by running `vite build` and you host those generated files somewhere. I recommend https://vercel.com/ as it's very easy to setup and it's free (up to a certain usage). This can be of course different when you need to get more dynamic with server processing. If you don't want 3rd party, use Raspberry PI as a server.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan Yeah, but like I said, that breaks vue-router and the proxies.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how exactly it breaks your vue-router and the proxies as well? The build command is meant to build the app in the form of static files no matter what kind of router you use. I work with React primarily, react-router and tanstack router both work well for me when building the app. I think there might be some sort of mishandling in your case setting up the router in the first place.

Comment: @AaronHessler You're supposed to configure a webserver (potentially nginx) in prod for routing, etc. You don't generally need npx serve because that's a job for a webserver.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is an odd question. It asks 'how to deploy' but 'without a 3rd party', which does not make sense. To deploy, you necessarily need a 3rd party as the host? If we assume that, then Syed is right - this is a standard task, which is well documented, eg https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy Furthermore the Q is very broad, needs more details or code, and tends towards being opinion based.

Comment: Aaron, welcome to Stack Overflow. I think this question needs a bit of work. Clarify the title - what do you mean without a 3rd party? If you have deployed in on a specific stack and are having problems with routing, then maybe narrow it down to that and we can help. Otherwise I think this is perhaps a bit broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you're finding yourself here, it's probably because you learn-as-you-go.
Now, first you have to understand what [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) is. Vite is a **bundler**, which means that it transforms all your assets and code into a single bundle. This bundle has an entry point, the `index.html`. You can deploy this entry-point along with its assets to different platforms like [Vercel](https://vercel.com). If you wish to host it yourself, you can use tools like [NGINX](http://nginx.org/). However, if you try this, you might notice that your router (like vue-router for example) no longer appears to be working. This is not the case, vue-router does exactly what it's supposed to do. It is NGINX that is incorrectly configured. NGINX serves your assets statically, meaning that something like `/about` will have NGINX looking for the file called `about.html` in the root directory of your `dist` build. Because this file does not exist, it throws a `404`.
**As you see, your client-side router does not have a chance to take over.** To avoid this you have to have NGINX configured to redirect ***all*** requests to your `index.html`. Now, regarding your proxy. **Vite proxies are for development only** to avoid conflict with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) policies. If you require a proxy, add an additional one in your NGINX config to take over in production.

*Hope this helps!*